# Let $A$ =$\left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right) $ with $a,b,c,d$ positive real numbers such that $a+b<1/2$ and $c+d<1/2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

Let $A$ =$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array} \right) $ with $a,b,c,d$ positive real numbers such that $a+b<1/2$ and $c+d<1/2$, then which of the following statements is FALSE?

> A. $I+A$ invertible

> B. $I-A$ invertible

> C. $I+A^2$ invertible

> D.there exists a natural number $m$ such that $I+A^m$ is not invertivle.

What I did I set some values of $a,b,c,d$ to test that option A and B FALSE. I am stuck in C and D option. Please help.

Comment: What was your choice to set $B$ false?

Comment: If $A$ is false then $D$ is automatically true.

Comment: $a=1/9=c,b=1/3=d$

Comment: A false means D true?????????

Comment: @tret:  with $a=c=1/9$ and $b=d=1/3$, $A$ is not invertible, but $I+A$ is; and if A. is false and $I+A$ is not invertible then $m=1$ shows D. is true

Comment: @tret yes, because $m=1$ is a natural number.

Comment: What about C?....

Comment: @Ninad "A is false" means $\exists A, I+A\text{ is not invertible}$ while "D is true" means $\forall A, \exists m, I+A^m\text{ is not invertible}$.  It is false that the former implies the latter...

Comment: @BrianMoehring I'm not sure I'm getting at your meaning. If $I+A$ is noninvertible, then there exists an $m$ ($m=1$ that is) such that $I+A^m$ is not invertible. I'm not sure why you're qualifying statement $D$ with a $\forall$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Let $n$ be an integer.   Is "$n$ is odd" a true statement? ... Is "$n$ is even" a true statement?

Comment: You might find [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Gershgorin%22+AND+%22math+stack%22+site:math.stackexchange.com&client=ms-android-samsung-ga-rev1&sxsrf=ALeKk00kdVHkshpEgIpkPKf0zmoK2Opo0Q:1595874858186&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmsJyQie7qAhXilIsKHVpGBQEQrQIoBHoECAYQBQ&biw=1261&bih=2372&dpr=2.63) useful.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I hope you understand the analogy.  More generally, in a multiple choice question of the form $$\text{Let } \psi(x). \\ \text{A. } \varphi_A(x) \\ \text{B. } \varphi_B(x) \\ \cdots$$ then saying A is true means $\forall x(\psi(x) \to \varphi_A(x))$ is true and saying A is false is the negation of that.  You seem to be arguing something like $$\forall x(\psi(x) \to (\lnot\varphi_A(x) \to \varphi_D(x)))$$ with which I agree in this particular question, but this tells us nothing about whether D is true or false.

Answer (score 0):

> What I did I set some values of $a,b,c,d$ to test that option A and B FALSE.

This doesn't sound right. By Gerschgorin's disc theorem, the eigenvalues of $A$ lies inside the union of closed discs $D(a,b)\cup D(d,c)$. Since $a,b,c,d>0$, the maximum distance from $D(a,b)\cup D(d,c)$ to the origin is $\max(a+b,c+d)$, which is smaller than $\frac12$. Hence $|\lambda|<\frac12<1$ for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$. It follows that the statements in A,B,C are true and the statement in D is false.